# Finding a curve that intersects any line on the plane

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

> **Question** Is there a curve on plane  such that **any** line on the plane *meets* it (a non zero ) finite times ?

What are the bounds on the number of  such intersections.

My question was itself inspired by [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1343444&#p1343444) "Can you draw circles on the plane so that every line intersects at least one of them but no more than 100 of them?"

Comment: Clearly if your curve is the graph of an odd polynomial, the number of intersections is at most the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: One possibility is a pair of parabolas, say one concave up and one concave down, situated so that they touch tangentially (or intersect) and therefore cannot be separated by a hyperplane.

Comment: Please try to make titles of questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: @CameronWilliams   Correct, but just being an odd degree polynomial; does not guarantee that every line in the plane will intersect it

Comment: @ARi: Actually it does imply that, except degree 1.

Comment: @hardmath correct and the cubic is just a special case of CameronWilliams comment

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question, but please try to keep your titles informative. I also changed your tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cubic parabola $$y=x^3$$ has this property. The max number of such intersections is given by the Fundamental theorem of algebra:

$$x^3=ax+b$$ can have at most 3 solutions.

Comment: Yes but will all of the solutions be real for all real (a,b) pairs

Comment: For any $a$, there will be only one real solution for all sufficiently large $|b|$.

Comment: I think the important fact here (i.e., relevant to the question), is that $\,x^3-ax-b=0\;$ has *always* at least one real solution and, of course, at most three different ones. Nice answer. +1

Comment: So the upper bound  for intersections will be three and the lower one 0.

Comment: Well, a tighter and *always* attainable lower bound is one, in fact...and this fulfills the question's conditions.

Comment: DonAntonio: there's no differentiable curve that meets every line in the plane _at most_ once, though, or even at most twice.  See my answer for details.

Comment: and what about asymptotic behaviour at infinity will there still be intersections there

Comment: perfect solution; but if we add *another* constraint for y=$x^3$ regarding its behavior; as the parameters tend to infinity, then the intersection constraint isn't satisfied at all – ARi 2 mins ago

Comment: @ARi: I'm not sure what you mean by the intersection constraint not being satisfied "at all" as parameters tend to infinity.  I created [a public chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/10676/discussion-of-finding-a-curve-that-intersects-any-line-on-the-plane?tab=general) if you wish to discuss further.

Answer (score 4):

As already shown, any cubic polynomial (and indeed, any odd-degree polynomial) has the requisite property by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

What's more, a simple perturbation argument should be enough to show that any (sufficiently) *smooth* curve that meets every line in at least one point will meet some lines in at least three points.  Consider a point tangent to the curve where the second derivative 'with respect to the tangent line' is non-zero; that is, a non-reflex tangent point, or locally extremal point.  (Such points must exist if the curve is non-trivial).  Now, consider pencils of lines 'near' this intersection point; displaced infinitesimally one way from the tangent, they must have another point of intersection with the curve, and this point can be made 'generic' so that it doesn't vanish under small perturbations.  Then displace infinitesimally the other direction; the 'generic' point of intersection is still a point of intersection, but the tangent turns into two points of intersection.