# In how few points can a continuous curve meet all lines?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497584/find-a-curve-with-a-finite-number-of-intersections-with-all-the-lines-on-the-pla/) (currently closed) question, I'm wondering about a related topic: given that we have a continuous parametric curve (that is, a curve of the form $(x=x(t), y=y(t))$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x(t), y(t)$ continuous functions) which meets every line in the plane, what is the minimum number of times it must meet some line?  If the curve is (twice?) differentiable then the answer is 'three' by perturbation arguments (consider lines on either side of a tangent point), but those arguments (or at least the ones that I've been able to put together) make more-or-less explicit use of the curve's smoothness.  I suspect that some variant of the Jordan Curve Theorem might be used to show that the answer isn't even, but without the differentiability hypothesis I'm not even sure that the answer can't just be 'one' (**EDIT:** of course it can't be a maximum of one intersection per line, as Karolis Juodelė points out below: just choose a line that goes between some two points on the curve! This also obviates the question I had about point sets, so I've removed that outright).  Can the perturbation argument be adapted to show that the minimum is three even for non-smooth curves, or is there some 'exotic' curve that meets each line no more than twice?

Comment: My question was itself inspired by [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1343444&#p1343444) "Can you draw circles on the plane so that every line intersects at least one of them but no more than 100 of them?"

Comment: @ARi I recommend editing your own question to include that link and the motivation in the problem statement; it may help with petitioning for reopening a solid question!

Comment: There is no curve that meets no line twice. Forget continuity, or meeting all lines. If there are two points in the curve, there is a line between them.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė So obvious!  Sometimes the easiest things are the hardest to see.  I'll amend my question...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: given that the curve meets every line in the plane, it seems that an argument can be made that there is no curve that meets any line exactly twice...

Comment: Also, it seems that "each line exactly once" is impossible, since a straight line will not meet any parallel lines, while any curvature in the line will cause @KarolisJuodelė 's point to take effect.

Comment: @abiessu, note that a straight line meets itself at infinitely many points.

Comment: Are we also considering the behaviour of the curve at infinity

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: very true, I had left that one out.  OP: do you already have examples of such curves?  Have you considered $y=e^x\sin x$?

Comment: Should we consider only Simply connected curves here what about ones which have holes/gaps ?

Comment: @abiessu: what do you mean by 'such curves'?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I mean, examples of curves that meet all lines.  I think $y=e^{x^2}\sin x$ is another, and is one that guarantees all lines meet either once or an even number of times.  Any curve that meets all lines must extend in an unbounded fashion in at least three directions such that each pair of directions has less than $180$ degrees of open space between its asymptotes...

Comment: @ARi: 'simply connected' isn't necessary (but it seems likely that any 'minimal' curve will be simply connected), but holes/gaps are eliminated by the continuity condition.

Comment: @abiessu The simplest such is $y=x^3$; see the linked question.  It must meet each line at least once (by the fundamental theorem of algebra) and can't meet any line more than three times.  Your $e^{x^2}\sin x$ example meets e.g. the line $y=0$ infinitely many times.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: ah, I see it more clearly now, thank you.  So unbounded in two directions is possible for such a curve.

Comment: Removing the "continuity" condition may lead to interesting results

Comment: @StevenStadnicki perfect solution; but if we add another constraint for y=$x^3$ regarding its behavior; as parameters tend to infinity, then the intersection constraint isn't satisfied