# A curve such that all lines on the plane intersect it : cont..

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Further to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497584/82412) question (which appears more or less settled);  "Is there a curve on plane such that any line on the plane meets it (a non zero ) finite times ?"

I ask now the upper bounds of the number of such intersections.....

> **Question** Is there a curve on plane such that any line on the plane meets it  atleast once  but no more than k times ( with atleast one line intersecting k times) ?

The issue concerning the lowest achievable bounds for such intersections has also been discussed [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497782/82412)

**EDIT**

- For the cases where upper bound is achieved I stipulate  that such
  case be  present at all points of the curve (except maybe for
  finitely many).
- We are also not forced to assume smoothness or even connectedness of
  the curve. (The **answer** as a set of points is  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506273/82412); through a non constructive proof)
- While "meeting" means intersection , Being tangent can be taken as a
  special case
- We also consider weather the constraints are satisfied as the curve moves towards $\infty$

Comment: It's not clear to me what your edit means. Do you mean that all but finitely many lines intersect the curve at less than $k$ points?

Comment: In every region of the curve there are lines which intersect it K times.

Comment: The interesting modification is not to raise the maximum, but to raise the minimum from 1 to 2.  That changes the problem greatly.

Comment: The minimum is being discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/497782/82412)

Comment: @Ross That's not hard. Take rectangular parabolas $xy=1, xy=-1$ and add the 4 points $(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$. Unless you want connected?

Comment: One way I can make sense out of the edit is that for every point on the curve, there should exist a line that intersects the curve $k$ times, and that point is one of the intersections. It seems like $k = 3$ can be handled by a cubic, but $k = 5$ may be problematic.

Comment: @CalvinLin: to me when speaking intuitively, a curve is connected.  I think it then cannot be done, but am not certain.  That is a nicer example than I thought would be out there, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k$ is odd and greater than 1, then the polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^k (x-i) $ will satisfy your conditions.

It is clear that any line will intersect this odd degree polynomial at least once. Any line will intersect this $k$ degree polynomial at most $k$ times. The line $y=0$ intersects this polynomial exactly $k$ times.

Comment: Great. Just for analysis if we add the constraint where the cases for k times intersections are required to be infinitely many ? ( as against possibly one in your answer).

Comment: @Ari There are infinitely many lines, of the form $ y = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is close to 0.

Comment: Correct but  majority of the curve is devoid of such cases, please see my Edit above

Comment: "odd," $\:\mapsto\:$ "odd and greater than 1," $\;\;\;$

Comment: As one sees there are intervals [a,b] where f(x) never gets intersected more than one times by a line.

Comment: @Ari Note that my solution was written up before your edit.