# Set of points in the plane which is intersected by every line on the plane and in which no more than K points are collinear

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

> 

- **Question** Let $K \in \mathbb{N} (K \geq 3)$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Either find a set $S$ of points in the plane such that every line on the plane intersects atleast one point in $S$  and  that no more than $K$ points in $S$ are collinear, or prove that there is no such set.

> - ***As an additional constraint the points should be so distributed that every <s>circle</s> *disc* of radius r  on the plane has at-least one   point which belongs to S***

References on related results would also be nice.

***Remark:*** The question is a kind of non-connected version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500941/82412) question " find a curve which intersects all lines on the plane at most $K$ times and at least once."

In a more general setting, we may replace the '<s>circle</s>disc'  constraint by a chosen  statistical distribution  of points.

**EDIT**

By finding it would be correct to mean a constructive
 proof

Comment: What do you mean by "devise"?

Comment: Can't I just start with some lattice with small enough mesh to easily
meet every $R$-disc, and then randomly perturb each point?  If you want
a completely explicit configuration, enumerate the lattice points
any way you lik and then move the $n$-th one by 
$(a_n\pi^{2^{2n+1}}, b_n\pi^{2^{2n+2}})$
for some nonzero rational $a_n,b_n$ small enough that the perturbation
is less than half the shortest lattice vector.

Comment: @ARi: I tried to improve the formulation of your question. This involved significant rephrasing, so please check.

Comment: At least right now, the question asks for a set which meets every circle, not every disk.

You can just do it (meaning, well-order the circles and choose appropriate points by transfinite induction). Were you hoping for something more explicit?

Comment: @StefanKohl thanks. a little rework and now it fine

Comment: @jamescranch  My mistake of writing circles whereas I meant the interior of those circles too, made the necessary changes I talk of a closed disc now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $K$ must be at least $2$.  Under AC (the Axiom of Choice), $K=2$
can be attained, even if we require $S$ to meet *every* circle, not just
circles of fixed radius.  The construction uses transfinite induction,
so "finds" $S$ only in a somewhat weak sense...

The set of lines and circles in the plane, call it $\Sigma$,
has cardinality $c$ (continuum).  Using AC we can well-order $\Sigma$
so for each $\alpha \in \Sigma$ there are fewer than $c$ lines and circles
preceding $\alpha$ in the order.  We now construct
$S = \{ p_\alpha : \alpha \in \Sigma \}$, where each
$p_\alpha \in \alpha$ is chosen inductively so that it is not collinear with
$p_\beta$ and $p_\gamma$ for any distinct $\beta,\gamma \prec \alpha$.
This is possible because there are $c$ points in $\alpha$ but the cardinality
of lines $\overline{p_\beta p_\gamma}$ with $\beta,\gamma \prec \alpha$
is less than $c$ (if a set has cardinality less than $c$
then so does its square), and each line meets $\alpha$ in at most two points.
This fails only if $\alpha$ happens to be the line joining some
$p_\beta$ and $p_\gamma$, but then $\alpha$ already has a point of $S$
so we can skip $\alpha$ (or declare that $p_\alpha = p_\beta$).
Then $S$ meets every line and every circle, and contains no three collinear points.

The same trick applies in greater generality; e.g. $S$ can be made
to meet every algebraic curve and have neither three collinear nor
four concyclic points.

(All this must be known already, but it's easier to write a proof
than find a reference.)

[**Added later** *I see now that James Cranch suggested this approach
in his comment on this question 
[on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142974)
before it was migrated here.*]

Comment: Very interesting; **specially since you prove a stronger result** of S meeting every circle.. a result which initially appears counter intuitive. I wonder though what would be an algorithmic approach to construct S. Say the first point in S is at origin the algorithm should give out the nth point for n as input.

Comment: In addition to above the algorithm; given any line (a,b) outputs  ($x_i,y_i$), 0<i<3 ; The three (max) collinear points which are on it and on given a disc  D cantered at (x,y) and radius r; outputs the coordinates of 'a' Point p$\in S \; and \; p \in D$

Comment: @ARi:  The problem is that we don't have an explicit well-order that is needed, and we can't define most of the points on a line.  We could say the well-order starts with $y=0, x^2+y^2=1, x=0, $ etc. The first point can be at the origin, but the next point can be anywhere on the unit circle and the next one can be almost anywhere on the $y$ axis.

Comment: @RossMillikan So do we  take it that, while set $S$ would exist, it is not describable  (as an extensional definition) by any mathematical function ? And while there may be infinite sets which qualify as $S$ our algorithm  needs to construct only one.

Comment: @ARi:  that is correct.  I believe there will be continuum many, but without AC there may not be one.